# js, древовидное отображение

Tags: javascript, массивы

Почему такая конструкция не работает?

Если вывести из div user div data - оно будет работать.

Но, увы не могу понять.

А задача передо мной такая - у меня есть массив подобно этому, в нём несколько id, хочу засунуть в первый див его lastname, а ниже в другом диве инфу к примеру, не совсем понимаю, как сделать вот такое:

```
John Lastname //div user
 Skype : 123 //div userExt
Dan Qwert //div user?
 Skype : 456 // div userExt?
```

При условии, что в массиве всё это будет ( я имею в виду несколько skype и соотв, несколько фио)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var person = {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 46,
    instagram: 123,
    skype: "Lamp"
  };
  var user = person['firstName'] + ' ' + person['lastName'];
  var userExt = person['id'] + ' ' + person['age'];
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = user;
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = userExt;
  //console.log (data);
};
```

```html
<div id="user">
  <div id="data">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уточню зачем я хочу отображать об одном юзере в разных дивах - по логике когда-то потом, мне нужно будет скрывать по условиям эти самые дивы нижнего уровня.

Comment: У вас один div перезаписывает другой, нужно их "развязать" например так `<div><span id=user /><div id=data /></div>` а то записывая user вы стираете data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var person = {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 46,
    instagram: 123,
    skype: "Lamp"
  };
  var user = person['firstName'] + ' ' + person['lastName'];
  var userExt = person['id'] + ' ' + person['age'];
  
  var data =  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = userExt;
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = user + data;
 
  //console.log (data);
};
```

```html
<div id="user">
  <div id="data">
  </div>
</div>
```

Когда вы меняете значение через document.getElementById("user").innerHTML, то все содержимое дива перезаписывается (включая все вложенные дивы и текст), можно скопировать заранее все содержимое дива и потом его добавить, либо развязать дивы

```html
<div>
    <div id="user">
    </div>
    <div id="data">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не _вызываете document.getElementById("user").innerHTML_, а _меняете значение document.getElementById("user").innerHTML_

Answer (score 1):

У тебя есть две строковые переменные user и userExt.

1. Когда ты пишешь  *document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = user;*, то твой код

```html
<div id="user">
  <div id="data">
  </div>
</div>

Становится таким:

<div id="user">"тут написано значение переменной user"</div>
```

2. Когда ты пишешь *document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = userExt;*, то интерпретатор не может найти объект div#data, так как его уже НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ в памяти. Вот и выдает ошибку.